# Modificar solo una fila del listview en Android

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un listview personalizado utiliza el `CustomAdapter` al dar click en una fila me manda a otro activity de modificacion, pero no quiero volver a recargar la lista es decir cuando se modifique el nombre en el otro activity al momento de regresar *¿como le hago para que en la fila que habia seleccionado se cambie el nombre sin recargar todo el listview?*

Asi entro con click:

```
registrados.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//En esta parte me manda al otro activity donde modifico la informacion en sqlite del elemento seleccionado

}
        });
```

Comment: Los datos los obtienes de una base de datos? O simplemente deseas enviar un valor de la Acyivity donde realizaste la edición?

Comment: lleno el **ListView** desde la base de datos `sqlite` y paso la informacion al otro activity con `putExtra` no se si me explico.

Comment: te recomiendo que en lugar de usar ListView uses [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) su adapter tiene un método [notifyItemChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) que hace lo que quieres. Ademas ya no se recomienda el uso de ListView

Comment: deberias enviar un intent extra, que indique que posición y dato se cambio, y luego desde la actividad padre (en donde esta el lisView) modifiques un dato

Answer (score 0):

Llamar *invalidate()* de *view* o *parent* debería solucionar tu problema:

```
registrados.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //En esta parte me manda al otro activity donde modifico la informacion en sqlite del elemento seleccionado
    view.invalidate();
    }
});
```